# Android less than api 23 couldnt connect to the server

Tags: android, api, rest

I have developed an android app , and all my users who has android less than api 23 couldnt connect to the server, and the rest just work normal, and that just started from this day (2020-05-30), before this day it was working normally for many years.
Any idea whats the reason. Is it from our ISP or from google it self.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a certificate expiry event today, could be related.

https://twitter.com/bitcynth/status/1266683552030212096

https://crt.sh/?id=1

Not certain this is the same thing - https://support.sectigo.com/articles/Knowledge/Sectigo-AddTrust-External-CA-Root-Expiring-May-30-2020

Probable options if you confirm this is the case

- Get the server team to issue a new certificate with a different root CA.
- Add a new Root CA to the device, but this requires a manual process on each phone.

Comment: whats that means

Comment: Read up https://twitter.com/StarrHorne/status/1266710915774181386

Comment: my issue related to this link https://support.sectigo.com/articles/Knowledge/Sectigo-AddTrust-External-CA-Root-Expiring-May-30-2020

Comment: but how to overcome this problem, any idea?